# How to reimplement the "all" function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

I need to define a function`all' :: ( a -> Bool ) -> [a] -> Bool` which verifies if all the elements from a list satisfy a certain condition .

For example : `all' ( <5) [1,2,3] = True` ,  `all' (>=2) [1,1,2,2,3,3]` = False.

My main problem is that I don't know how to handle the transmission of a function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functions in Haskell are passed just like any other value. Here's an example to help you progress:

```
doBothSatisfy :: (a -> Bool) -> a -> a -> Bool
doBothSatisfy p x y = (p x) && (p y)
```

And now the usage:

```
doBothSatisfy (> 5) 6 7 == True
doBothSatisfy (> 5) 1 8 == False
```

Now try to extend that to lists.

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly. My programs looks like:       **Alternative 1**:
`all'  :: (a->Bool) -> [a] ->Bool
all' fct [] = True
all' fct (x:xs) = ( fct x ) && ( all' fct  xs )`

**Alternative 2**:
`all''::(a->Bool)->[a]->Bool

all'' f []= False
all'' f (x:[])=if f x then True else False
all'' f (x:xs)=if f x then all'' f xs else False`

Comment: @kissylips if you make the empty array case be `True`, you can get rid of the 2nd condition.

Comment: @kissylips looks correct. Just some notes: `x:[]` can also be written as `[x]` (brackets can be used both for making and pattern matching lists). Also `if whatever then True else False` is always the same as `whatever`. Also, a good place to put small bits of code is http://lpaste.net/.